# Application is crashing when testing it on a real device

Tags: iphone, ios, crash

I am developing one app. While I am running this app in real device it crashes. Actually in application is taking picture and store in private document folder after that I am retrieving that image from private folder and displaying in thumbnail. For that I am using F Gallery project. By using this i am displaying images in thumbnail like photo gallery view.

If i take more images means its taking so much time to load all images and after that is crashing the application and automatically switch OFF and switch ON the device.

In console it's showing error like this below.

Canany body tell me  why it's crashing? And how to solve this problem?

```
Jan  4 18:45:50 Primusblr profiled[3448] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Idled.
Jan  4 18:45:50 Primusblr profiled[3448] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Service stopping.
Jan  4 18:45:59 Primusblr UserEventAgent[15] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
Jan  4 18:46:00 Primusblr com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[3437]) <Notice>: (com.apple.lsd) Exited: Killed: 9
Jan  4 18:46:00 Primusblr com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.assetsd[3479]) <Notice>: (com.apple.assetsd) Exited: Killed: 9
Jan  4 18:46:00 Primusblr com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.networkd_privileged[3458]) <Notice>: (com.apple.networkd_privileged) Exited: Killed: 9
Jan  4 18:46:00 Primusblr com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.softwareupdateservicesd[3462]) <Notice>: (com.apple.softwareupdateservicesd) Exited: Killed: 9
Jan  4 18:46:00 Primusblr com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.coreservices.appleid.authentication[3441]) <Notice>: (com.apple.coreservices.appleid.authentication) Exited: Killed: 9
Jan  4 18:46:00 Primusblr com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.accountsd[3392]) <Notice>: (com.apple.accountsd) Exited: Killed: 9
Jan  4 18:46:00 Primusblr com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.mobile.installd[3435]) <Notice>: (com.apple.mobile.installd) Exited: Killed: 9
Jan  4 18:46:00 Primusblr com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.timed[3433]) <Notice>: (com.apple.timed) Exited: Killed: 9
Jan  4 18:46:00 Primusblr com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.itunesstored[3446]) <Notice>: (com.apple.itunesstored) Exited: Killed: 9
```

Comment: Please post the affected source code in your question.

Comment: Jetsam often relates to memory issues. Have you run it through Instruments?

Comment: Yep. From the look of your messages it looks like you are seriously running out of memory. Your app must be sucking all other memory. Not it is killing other processes, and you probably haven't implemented a way to catch these. Are you using ARC?

Comment: Haan Acctually iam using ARC but i am using third party lib THats FGallery project its not ARC.